# How to read input in Google Kickstart (PHP)

Tags: php

How can I read following stdin for Google Kickstart oder Jam code etc.:

```
4
1 9
91 99
451 460
501 1000
```

So the 4 in the first line has to be in a var (e.g. $a);
Then in every line after that:
the first param goes into an Array of $b[] e.g.
And the same with the second param. In $c[] e.g.
So the result should be:

lang: PHP

```
$a = "4";
$b = ["1", "91", "451", "501"];
$c = ["9", "99", "460", "1000"];
```

It doesn't matter if it's an integer or a string.

Thank you

Comment: Is that a exercise / homework?

Comment: It is for Google Kickstart, which is a website for competitive programming :). I know php isn't the best language for this but I want to start with a lang I can use

Comment: Hey @GetGetCoded! Yes i googled it yesterday . Did my answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71593971/14807111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think so, like this?

```php
<?php
$str="4
1 9
91 99
451 460
501 1000";

$t = explode("\n", $str);
print_r($t);

foreach($t as $r) {
    $n[] = explode(" ",$r);
}
$a = array_shift($n)[0]; 
$b = [];
foreach($n as $v) {
    $b[] = $v[0];
    $c[] = $v[1];
}

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
print_r($c);
```

**output**

```php
4
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 91
    [2] => 451
    [3] => 501
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 99
    [2] => 460
    [3] => 1000
)
```